# Secondary database log file in alwayson is very big

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, availability-groups

I have an alwayson environment (AlwaysOn AG). 
Database [UsersDb] in the slave server, His log file is very big .
How can I reduce his size(shrink)?

Comment: Can you let us know just how big - big - is. The size of the database and log files on both nodes will help a lot

Comment: 600 G in both server . Primary and secondary.

Comment: The log an databse . Log 600 G data 800 G .

Comment: If you have 600GB worth of log files on the primary you should expect 600GB of log files on the secondary. Quite normal.

Comment: Forgot to ask, do you have a tlog backup job scheduled and how frequently

Comment: Whatever the log is on the primary the log will be on all of the secondary servers. If this is a problem, approach it from the primary point of view as all actions will be sent to connected secondary servers.